# How do you refer to primitive Java types in Clojure?

Tags: java, clojure, java-interop

I'd like to use reflection to get a method of a Java object from Clojure. One of the argument types is a Java primitive and I don't know how to refer to them from Clojure.

For example, say I wanted to get [`String.valueOf(boolean)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(boolean)). My nearest guess would be to do

```
(.getDeclaredMethod String "valueOf" (into-array [Boolean]))
```

but this fails because `Boolean` is not the primitive type itself, but the boxed version. I've tried `boolean`, but that refers to a built-in Clojure function, and `bool` is undefined.

How do I refer to a primitive Java type in Clojure?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can refer to the primitive types through the `TYPE` property of their boxed equivalent. For example:

```
user=> (.getDeclaredMethod String "valueOf" (into-array [Boolean/TYPE]))
#<Method public static java.lang.String java.lang.String.valueOf(boolean)>
```

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, if you want to find the Java Class object for an array of primitives, you can use this trick [from the `tupelo.types` namespace](https://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.types.html):

```
; An instance of the java.lang.Class<XXXX[]> (e.g. java.lang.Class<Byte[]>). 
(def ^:private  class-boolean-array (.getClass (boolean-array   0)))
(def ^:private  class-byte-array    (.getClass (byte-array      0)))
(def ^:private  class-char-array    (.getClass (char-array      0)))
(def ^:private  class-double-array  (.getClass (double-array    0)))
(def ^:private  class-float-array   (.getClass (float-array     0)))
(def ^:private  class-int-array     (.getClass (int-array       0)))
(def ^:private  class-long-array    (.getClass (long-array      0)))
(def ^:private  class-object-array  (.getClass (object-array    0)))
(def ^:private  class-short-array   (.getClass (short-array     0)))
```

This is used for type testing such as:

```
(defn boolean-array?
  "Returns true is the arg is a boolean array, else false."
  [arg]
  (= class-boolean-array (.getClass arg)))
```